# Input method WYSIWYG editor not storing values in mysql database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ckeditor

I am using WYSIWYG editor to input job description in my portal but it is not storing the values in to the databe
here is my code

```
       <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="jtitle">Job Title</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="jtitle" name="jtitle" placeholder="Enter job title">
  </div>
</div>   
     <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="duration">Job Duration</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="duration" name="duration" placeholder="Enter duration">
  </div>
</div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="budget">Budget</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Budget" name="budget" placeholder="Enter Budget">
  </div>
</div>
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="keyskills">Key Skills</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyskills" name="keyskills"placeholder="Enter Skills">
  </div>
</div>
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="jobdescription">Job Description</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="textarea" rows="1000" class="form-control" id="jobdescription" name="jobdescription" placeholder="Enter Job Description">
   <script type="text/javascript">
          CKEDITOR.replace( 'jobdescription' );
   </script>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="edate">Expiry Date</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="date" class="form-control" id="edate" name="edate" placeholder="Click to enter expiry date">
  </div>
</div>
      <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="cdexmin">Candidate Experience Minimum</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cdexmin" name="cdexmin" placeholder="Enter Minimum Experience">
  </div>
</div>
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="cdexmax">Candidate Experience Maximum</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cdexmax" name="cdexmax" placeholder="Enter Maximum Experience">
  </div>
     </div>
        <div class="form-group">        
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit"  name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Post Job</button>
         </div>
         </div>
        </form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      try {
           // Establish server connection and select database
           $username=$_SESSION['username'];

           $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM employer  
                      INNER JOIN  company ON employer.cid= company.cid  
                      WHERE employer.username='$username' ");
           $stmt->execute();
           $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
           $cid=$row['cid'];
           $eid=$row['eid'];
           $jtitle=$_POST['jtitle'];
           $duration=$_POST['duration'];
           $budget=$_POST['budget'];
           $keyskills=$_POST['keyskills'];
           $jobdescription=$_POST['jobdescription'];
           $edate=$_POST['edate'];
           $cdexmin=$_POST['cdexmin'];
           $cdexmax=$_POST['cdexmax'];
           $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 
                     job(cid,eid,jtitle,duration,budget,
                         keyskills,jdesc,edate,
                         cdexmin,cdexmax)
                  values('$cid','$eid','$jtitle','$duration','$budget',
                         '$keyskills','$jobdescription','$edate',
                         '$cdexmin','$cdexmax') ");

           $stmt->execute();
           $result="Successfully Job Posted to view your Job It should be activated by Admin";
           header("Location:/emprdash?success=1");
     } catch(PDOException $e){
          echo "Error occurs:". $e->getMessage();
     }   
   }
?>
```

All values are entering but job description only not updating i downloaded ckeditor and also uploaded the files in  to the server and i attached javascript ckeditor.js in my page but is not updating the values in to the form is there any errors or what can i do for this

Answer (score 3):

Gowri, There is no textarea type available in input tag so please change Following code

```
<input type="textarea" rows="1000" class="form-control" id="jobdescription" name="jobdescription" placeholder="Enter Job Description">
```

to

```
<textarea rows="1000" class="form-control" id="jobdescription" name="jobdescription" placeholder="Enter Job Description"></textarea>
```

Comment: thank you so vipul jethav i didn't recognize it , i appreciate your work